# Undefined variable: results

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

1. Model

   ```
   public function show()
   {
       $query = $this->db->get('text');
       return $query->result();
   }
   ```

2.Controller

```
    public function inf()
    {
        $this->load->model('addm');
        $data['results'] = $this->addm->show($query);

        $this->load->view('backend/first',$data);

    }
```

3.view

I am trying to get the data from my db but i can't solve this error:
 Undefined variable: result

```
<?php
echo"<td>";

if (is_array($result)) {
   foreach ($result() as $row) {
       $id = $row->id;
       $words = $row->words;
      } 
}

echo "</td>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things,

- In your model function show is not ***expecting*** any parameters
- Remove `$query` from `$this->addm->show();` as not needed
- In the view variable should be **results** not **result**

  ```
  // controller
  public function inf()

  {
      $this->load->model('addm');
      $data['results'] = $this->addm->show();
      $this->load->view('backend/first', $data);
  }


  // view
  if (!empty($results)) {
      foreach($results as $row) {
          $id = $row->id;
          $words = $row->words;
      }
  }

  // model
  public function show()

  {
      $query = $this->db->get('text');
      return $query->result();
  }
  ```

Comment: model public function show()
 {
  
   $query = $this->db->get('text');
   return $query->result();
 

 } controller public function inf()
  {
   $this->load->model('addm');
   $data['results'] = $this->addm->show();
   
   $this->load->view('backend/first',$data);

  }model <?php
      echo"<td>";

    if (is_array($results)) {
     foreach ($results as $row) {
           $id = $row->id;
           $words = $row->words;
          } 
    }
      

    
   echo "</td>"; 
    ?> //i still have this error

Comment: @zeko50 please tell me the error your getting..and check the above code

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: results

Filename: backend/first.php

Line Number: 74

Comment: @zeko50 please update your code with mine above..in your view file

Comment: @zeko50 i have updated my code above please check now

Comment: i'm sorry i updat it now and it  give me no result and no error

Comment: @zeko50 try passing a static value to results and `print_r($results)` in view..what is your CI version?

Comment: did you try print_r ? with static value?

Comment: yes but have a look on it i guss it wrong controller $data['d'] = print_r($results); view echo $results->$d; and it's give me nothing

Comment: No use it like this in controller `$data['d'] = 'help'` and in view `echo $d;`

Comment: it doesn't passing the data it gave me this error Undefined variable

Comment: @zeko50 how are you executing the function?

Comment: Tell me the way your calling the controller file

Comment: do you mean that ? <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

Comment: No i mean the url your accessing the file eg: `http://www.site/index.php/yourcontroller/function` ?

Comment: Now try the `$result` as `$data['results'] = $this->addm->show();` tell me the result

Comment: @zeko50 Please accept this answer and vote..Your welcome

Comment: @zeko50 anytime contact me through stack-overflow. Right here to help you.